# adding content to tab/dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's see if I can explain this.

I have the following code that makes certain content appear depending on the tab that is clicked on:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="no-list-style">js
        <li class="active information-tab">
            <div class="information-dropdown"><a rel="info" href="#">{{ 'Information' | t }}</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="active program-tab">
            <div class="program-dropdown"><a rel="info" href="#">{{ 'Program' | t }}</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have added the program tab myself. I need the content that appears when this program tab is used to be added using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$('#addedDiv').contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3 }).each(function () { this.parentNode.innerHTML = this.textContent.replace('','This is the program'); });
// ]]></script>
```

I know somewhere a div with id "addedDiv" needs to be added for this, but where and how?

Answer (score 1):

For your code it is necessary that your 'addedDiv' contains at least a space, so use this

```
<div id="addedDiv">&nbsp;</div>
```

You can place this whereever it is needed.

Take a look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bu4q63ft/

Add it here in your page:

```
<div class="tabsPage">
    <div class="page info">...</div>

    <div class="page programs">
        <div id="addedDiv">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

    <div class="page reviews">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I need the text "This is the program" only to seen when the program tab is used. Where do I place the code `<div id="addedDiv">&nbsp;</div>` so this happens.

Comment: Just put the <div id="addedDiv">&nbsp;</div> into your actual tab, which is triggered by the program link. If you post the remainder of your html as well as the jquery used for the tabs, I'll take a look at it and should be able to tell you where exactly to put it.

Comment: [This is where it should happen ](http://www.photographycoursetour.com/japan-tour-beginners-course.html#) See the tabs "information", "program", "testimonials" on the left of the page above the video. When the program tab is used the text "This is the program" should show below the tab, as does other content when the other two tabs are used.

Comment: I added the lines where you need to place it in my answer. Make sure however that it gets hidden by your jquery and shown when clicked.

Comment: Thanks Silence. Turns out I needed to adapt a number of things in conjunction with your solution. Got it working now.

Comment: Glad to help! If your problem is solved, could you mark the question as answered so it gets closed please?